# Unable to refresh UITableView when rows are deleted

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` having many rows that contains `UITextFields`. User enters data to these fields. user can delete or add any rows. When i am trying to delete any row it deletes the correct row from the array(that contains all the cell's reference) but the `UITextfield` always shows that the last row is deleted.

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return  _countEmailValues.count ;
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CustomEmailCell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[LACustomEmailCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.emailTextField.tag = 555;
    cell.deleteEmailFieldButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"delete email Field tag %i",cell.deleteEmailFieldButton.tag );
    cell.emailTextField.delegate = self;

    if ([_countEmailValues count] > 1  )
    {
        cell.deleteEmailFieldButton.hidden = false;
    }
    else
    {
         cell.deleteEmailFieldButton.hidden = true;
    }

    // Reason why I am adding cell.emailtextfield in this delegate? is should be in addButtonclick but cell.emailtextfield is not
    // initialized there. Also adding of only cell will give null for the emailTextField.
    // So adding all cells here and then removing duplicates entires and accessing over the app.

    [_emailValues addObject:cell.emailTextField];

    // Remove Duplicate elements.
    NSArray *emailFieldCollection  = [_emailValues copy];
    NSInteger index = [emailFieldCollection count ] -1;

    for (id object in [emailFieldCollection reverseObjectEnumerator])
    {
        if ([_emailValues indexOfObject:object inRange:NSMakeRange(0, index)] != NSNotFound)
        {
            [_emailValues removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        }

        index--;
    }

    NSLog(@"Row : %i",indexPath.row);
    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)deleteEmailClick:(UIButton *)sender
{
   NSIndexPath *index =  self.emailTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
   // [self.emailTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:0];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_emailTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSLog(@"Tags %i", sender.tag);

//    [self.emailTableView reloadData];

    if ([_countEmailValues count] > 0)
    {
        [  _countEmailValues  removeObjectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    }
      //  NSLog(@"array after %@",_countEmailValues);
    if ([_countEmailValues count] == 0)
    {
       // _deleteEmailButton.hidden = true;
        _doneButton.hidden = true;
    }

    NSLog(@"array before %@",_emailValues);
    if ([_emailValues count] > 0)
    {
        [_emailValues removeObjectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    }

    [self.emailTableView reloadData];
    }
```

The `_emailValues` gets updated properly but the data in the fields is always getting cleared of the last one.
EX: in the image if i delete "b" the `_emailValues` gets cleared properly but the ui shows two field having data "a" & "b" . what have i missed here?
pls help.
[image]

Comment: Does _countEmailValues get updated properly?

Comment: [_emailValues addObject:cell.emailTextField]; might create some issue..check this line

Comment: @souvickcse yes its updated . samkit Jain. what to you mean..i am trying to add cell reference to the array.

Comment: Where are you setting cell.emailTextField.text value?

Comment: its not required to set the text value. as i have captured the reference of field so when any text will be updated it will be reflected.

Comment: You should never save your cell references, since cells are reused and recycled. If you want to delete or add any row, just use `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` and `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`

Comment: @EngrAnum my bad that i said cell.its cell.emailTExtfield. hope thats okay to save?

Comment: May i ask, why do you wish to save them ? Probably we'll be able to tell you another way of getting to your end result

Comment: ya sure..if the user deletes the second field then it should delete the second row. just provides the flexibility to the user to delete the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You are not deleting the cell . In `deleteEmailClick` add this line

```
[self.emailTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

Also I would like to point out another way of implementing delete using a block. This will ensure that you always have the correct cell and no need to tag your delete button. This would be cleaner and maintainable. In your custom cell class `LACustomEmailCell` declare a block property like so

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) void (^deleteButtonTappedBlock)();
```

Connect the IBAction of your delete button in the `LACustomEmailCell` class and from there call this block. I am assuming the name as `deleteButtonPressed`

```
- (IBAction)deleteButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    self.deleteButtonTappedBlock();
}
```

Now in `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

You can set the block like this

```
[cell setDeleteButtonTappedBlock:^(){
        //Action to perform when cell is deleted. In your case the code in `deleteEmailClick` will go here.
       //In the end delete the cell.
        [self.emailTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }];
```

i hope this helps